# I have managed to compile java-program but I cannot execute it

Tags: java, class, executable

I have just installed JDK on Windows Vista. After that I set proper values for the 4 environment variables: classpath, include, lib, path. After that I was able to compile my HelloWorld-program (I got a *.class file). But when I try to execute the compiled program (I type java HelloWorldApp) it does not work. The Java write a lot of stuff and in the end it is written that it "could not find the main class: HelloWorldApp". Can anybody, pleas, help me with this problem?

Comment: are you in the directory with your .class and .java file? I have never used the command-line for executing java code, I fall back on the IDE's

Comment: Yes, I am in the directory with my *.class and *.java files.

Comment: Do you have the proper signature for your main method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. create a file called `HelloWorld.java`;
2. paste the code posted below inside `HelloWorld.java`:
3. compile it by executing the command: `javac HelloWorld.java` in the same folder as HelloWorld.java is in;
4. execute the code by doing: `java -cp . HelloWorld` in the same folder as HelloWorld.java is in.

---

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("HelloWorld works!");
    }
}
```

How the classpath works, can be read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29

Comment: BTW, that wikipedia page is not entirely correct for the Sun JDK. On the Sun JDK, the default classpath includes the current directory, unless it is overridden. <http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html> for details.

Comment: I must confess that I did not read the entire Wiki-entry, but if parts of it are incorrect (not sure by your comment which part you mean...) you could perhaps edit it (that's what Wikipedia is all about, right?).

Answer (score 5):

Just for clarity; you are saying that you have a class in the default package, that is you have not included a package specifier in the Java file, and your class is called `HelloWorldApp`. When you compiled this, you got a classfile `HelloWorldApp.class` in the current directory.

Assuming the above to be true then try:

```
java -cp . HelloWorldApp
```

For example, the following works on a unix box:

```
$ echo 'class HelloWorldApp { public static void main(String []argv) { System.out.println("Hello World!"); } }' > HelloWorldApp.java
$ javac HelloWorldApp.java 
$ java -cp . HelloWorldApp 
Hello World!
```

Of course, you should indent your code a little nicer than just shoving the whole thing onto one line ;-)

**Edit**: To answer the comment:

Normally, the default classpath is the runtime libraries and [the current directory](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html). However, if you have the `CLASSPATH` variable set, then this will override the default, and you need to explicitly set the classpath back to its "default value". To verify if the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is set, you can do (again assuming unix):

```
set | grep CLASSPATH
```

If it is set, that is why you need to manually include `.` on your classpath.

Comment: OK. It works! If I type "java -cp . HelloWorldApp" I get the "Hello World!". But I still need to figure out why.

Comment: @Roman, the *why* can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29

Comment: @Bart: That is the wrong why ;-) I have updated my answer to explain the most probable cause. Certainly, on my box I do not _need_ to specify the classpath, and it still works.

Comment: Perhaps it is, perhaps not. By Roman's remark "why" it works (or why not), I guessed Roman was unfamiliar what happens behind the scenes when a Java application is being executed. I think the WIki article gives a good overview of this process (also see the links at the bottom of that page). Also note that you need not assume Roman is running a *nix like OS (see the first sentence of the original question) :)

Comment: @Bart: You are right... however, I don't have a Windows system to test on :-).  My wording is probably a little strong, certainly I think the problem is likely to be a globally set CLASSPATH, but I cannot be certain of that…

Comment: Yes, I share your belief about the globally set CLASSPATH (which should be banned, btw!) :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you included `.` and `..` in your path? Just for clarification . represents your current directory and .. represents your parent directory. You are telling that the java has to search the current directory and the parent directory to find the class. Add the same to your classpath too.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use:

```
java -cp {path to directory with HelloWorldApp in it} HelloWorldApp
```

That path should be contained within your `CLASSPATH` environment variable. Is that exported to your command shell ? Do you need to start a new command shell to get the most recent version of `CLASSPATH` ?

Answer (score 0):

Post your code.  I believe the problem is that your main class is not defined properly.  I did this the other day.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class path concept and the logical difference between Java source code and compiled byte code is notoriously hard to get right.

I would strongly recommend you familiarize yourself with the Sun Java Tutorial.  The relevant section is

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html