# Why Java could not find the main class?

Tags: java, class

I have just copied Key-Listener code from http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/KeyEventDemoProject/src/events/KeyEventDemo.java. I was able to compalie it with the "javac" command. But when I try to execute the compiled code (typing "java KeyEventDemo") I have a large message in the end of which I see:

```
Could not find the main class: KeyEventDemo.  Program will exit.
```

Yesterday I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133353/i-have-managed-to-compile-java-program-but-i-cannot-execute-it) on Windows Vista (now I am on Ubuntu). In the Windows I was able to solve the problem by typing "java -cp . ProgramName" or alternatively by adding new values ("." and "..")to the environment variable "classpath".

On Ubuntu the first solution does not work. I mean, when I type "java -cp . KeyEventDemo" I still have the problem. Moreover, on Ubuntu I was able to run other programs just typing "java ProgramName".

So, can anybody tell me what is special about this KeyEventDemo? Why it does not wont to work and how it can be solved?

Comment: You just have a single file, why not remove the package name for now? It works fine for me when I remove that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the *KeyEvent* class is in package *events*.

You either have to remove the *package events;* line from source code, or compile it with:

```
javac -d . KeyEventDemo.java
```

Answer (score 7):

The class `KeyEventDemo` is in a package `events` To run it, you must be in the *parent* folder of the `events` folder that contains the class, and run it using its fully qualified name, including the package:

```
java events.KeyEventDemo
```

The classpath must contain the folder (or JAR) that's the root of the folder hierarchy that represents the packages; the current folder is (I believe) included automatically.

Answer (score 5):

This program is not in the default package, but in the package "events": use `java -cp . events.KeyEventDemo` from the directory containing the folder "events":

```
   +work
    +events
     -KeyEventDemo.class
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you compile and run with diferent java version.
This is common when you try to execute an example at eclipse.

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow. This question was answered almost 3 years ago and the problem was already identified. Next time please first read the existing answers and check if one has been accepted or not before you provide an answer on an old question.