# could not find the main class java error

Tags: java, unix

I was having trouble with a could not find main class error with a somewhat complicated program I was working on. To eliminate possible problems I decided to try a hello world program to see if I could get that to work. I am working on a server which I'm pretty sure is running Red Hat Enterprise 6. I followed these steps provided by Bart Kiers in answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133353/i-have-managed-to-compile-java-program-but-i-cannot-execute-it?lq=1):

1. create a file called HelloWorld.java;
2. paste the code posted below
3. inside HelloWorld.java: compile it by executing the command: javac
   HelloWorld.java in the same folder as HelloWorld.java is in;
4. execute the code by doing: java -cp . HelloWorld in the same folder as
   HelloWorld.java is in.

I get the following error after the last step:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld/
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld.
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: HelloWorld.. Program will exit.
```

If I type java -version, the version info displays, suggesting that my PATH variable is set correctly. Does anyone have any other suggestions for things that might be causing this error? Thanks!

Comment: Did you see the HelloWorld.class in the folder?

Comment: What is this trailing `/` at the end of HelloWorld in the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are putting an  period at the end of your class name:

```
java -cp . HelloWorld.
```

Do this instead

```
java -cp . HelloWorld
```

Comment: Ah, I was actually slightly disobeying the directions and typing HelloWorld.class instead of just HelloWorld, which is where the period came from. How silly of me! Thanks so much for your help :)